# Цикл с двойным условием

Tags: c++, c, циклы

Здравствуйте! Как можно задать диапазон цикла с двойным условием? Например, если `zone == 0`, то цикл по `i` должен пробегать в диапазоне `(i < 6 && i > 19)`, если `zone == 1`, то  `(i > 6 && i < 19)`, ну и если `zone == 2`, то по всем `i`.

```
      for(int zone = 0; zone < nzones; zone++){     
         Gr[izone] = 0;
         for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
           for(int side = 0; side < 2; side++){
              for(int run = 0; run < 2; run++){
                 for(int ell = 0; ell < 40; ell++){
                    Gr[izone] += Gr[i][side][run][ell];
                 }
              }
           } 
       }
```

Comment: попробуйте использовать if или switch.

Comment: Не ясны нижняя и верхняя границы для `i<6 && i>19`. А 4х-мерный массив `Gr[i][side][run][ell]` это уж черезчур.

Comment: Нижняя i=0, а верхняя i=25. Ну а массив это файлы которые нужно разделять по сторонам, направлению и ячейкам с данными внутри

Answer (score 2):

1. Делаем цикл по всему диапазону `[0, 25)`;
2. Заводим функцию от индекса и зоны, которая возвращает `true` если элемент требует обработки;
3. Объединяем всё это.

---

```
bool use(int zone, int i) {
     switch(zone) {
         case 0: return i < 6 || i > 19;
         case 1: return i > 6 && i < 19;
         default: return true;
     } 
}

for(int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
     if(use(zone, i)) {
          // обрабатываем элемент
     }
}
```

---

Для сокращения кол-ва итераций можно использовать иной подход: возвращать для каждой пары {индекс, зона} следующий индекс.

```
int inc(int zone, int i) {
     ++i;
     switch(zone) {
         case 0: {
             if(i >= 6 && i <= 19) {
                 i = 20; // следующий после разрыва
             }
             break; 
         }
         case 1: { 
             if(i < 6) {
                 i = 6;
             }
             else if(i > 19) { 
                 i = 25; // последний в диапазоне
             }
         }
     }
     return i; 
}
```

По сути, это будет предварительная реализация идеи итераторов, которую предложил @igor-karpenko в своем ответе.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i = inc(zone,i) {
    // обрабатываем элемент
}
```

P.S. все "магические" константы надо, конечно же, заменить на именованные. В общем, не стоит воспринимать предложенный код как готовый для реализации. Это всего лишь набросок для демонстрации идеи.

Comment: Минус в том, что перебирает все возможные варианты. Для 25 итераций ерунда, конечно, но...

Comment: Не лучший вариант, ибо будет тратится процессорное время на вызов функции.

Comment: @Harry, зато всё предельно ясно. Для сокращения кол-ва итераций доработал ответ.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко процессорное время имеет смысл оценивать соответствующими утилитами. Код в первую очередь должен быть понятен для программиста. А преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если бы диапазоны были неразрывными (не как при `zone==0`), то было бы просто:

```
for(int zone=0; zone < nzones; zone++)
{
    for(i = (zone == 1) ? 7 : 0; i < (zone == 1) ? 19 : 26; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

Но обрабатывать разрывный диапазон придется либо двумя `for`, либо одним `for` по всему диапазону с проверкой, типа:

```
for(int zone=0; zone < nzones; zone++)
{
    for(i = (zone == 1) ? 7 : 0; i < (zone == 1) ? 19 : 26; i++)
    {
        if ((zone == 0) && (i >= 6) && (i <=19)) continue;
        ...

    }
}
```

Лучше навскидку что-то ничего не придумывается...
Конечно, в плане эффективности лучше расписать три отдельных случая и не терять время на проверки на каждой итерации...

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 0;
b = 27;

if (zone == 1)
    a = 6;

for (int i = a; i < b+1; )
{
//Ваши вычисления
    i++;
    if (zone == 0 && i == 6) i = 19;
    if (zone == 1 && i == 20) break;
}
```

Comment: Задавать границы мешает разрыв в диапазоне. Например, для нулевой зоны: 0-5, 20-25.

Comment: @alexolut а, дак вот оно что было, а что мешает в цикле "перескакивать"?

Comment: @dopecat Автор, предоставьте полное ТЗ в плане границ, тогда смогу записать как сделать.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко Итак, первая граница при zone==0 переменная цикла пробегает от (i=0; i<6) и (i>19; i<26). При zone==1 (i>6; i<20). И наконец при zone==2 (i=0; i<26). Для каждого случая полученная сумма Gr[zone]  делится на 608, 880 и 1488 соответственно. На самом деле, предложенный господином alexolut  метод дал необходимый результат (за что ему большое спасибо), но Ваше предложение также интересно.

Comment: @dopecat Надеюсь я вас правильно понял, отредактировал ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен подходит ли такое под Ваш случай, но я бы описал бы класс, который инкапсулировал бы в себе алгоритм итерации и переопределил бы в наследниках метод `getIterator()`, который возвращал бы подходящий диапозон `i` для конкретного экземпляра.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант проверки известных диапазонов, здесь можно задавать несколько диапазонов более 2.

```
enum
{
 ZONE_1 = 0,
 ZONE_2,
 AMOUNT_ZONE 
}

#define SIZE_ZONE      5
int array_zone[SIZE_ZONE] = {ZONE_1,ZONE_1,ZONE_2,ZONE_1,ZONE_1};

#define CHECK_ZONE_1        (ZONE_1+ZONE_1)
#define CHECK_ZONE_2        (ZONE_1+ZONE_2)
check_zone(int zone)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0;i<SIZE+ZONE;i++){
    int z = array_zone[i] + zone;
    switch(z){
      case (CHECK_ZONE_1):
        /*zone 1*/
        break;
      case (CHECK_ZONE_2);
        /*zone 2*/
        break
      default:
        /*all zone*/  
        break;
    }
  }
}

check_zone(ZONE_1);
```